# Combining Shell and Gnuplot script

Tags: string, gnuplot

I have the following problem:

I want to use a loop to plot data from different files (named `file1.dat, file2.dat, ...` in this example) in just one output-plot. I use this in a shell script to do so:

```
plot for [i=1:6] u 1:2 'file'.i.'.dat'
```

Now I additionally want to only plot a certain range of lines from each file. To do this I learned to use:

```
plot "<(sed -n '1,100p' file.dat)"  u 1:2
```

Anyhow, if I want to combine these two like:

```
plot for [i=1:6] "<(sed -n '1,100p' file'.i.'.dat)"  u 1:2
```

clearly the `i` within the expression giving the filename `file'.i.'.dat` to `sed` cannot be interpreted as the variable `i`. The error I get is:

```
sed: can't read file_.i..dat: No such file or directory
```

Do you have any suggestions how to circumvent this problem or other approaches to achieve my goal?

Comment: if you're getting an awk error, then you're using awk and not showing us. Could you share enough of the script for someone else to be able to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Did you try with matching quotes for `i` to be interpreted as variable: `plot for [i=1:6] "<(sed -n '1,100p' file".i.".dat)"  u 1:2`?

Comment: You should be able to use `every ::0::99`  to select the first 100 data points.

Comment: On a side note: `sed -n 1,100p` is better written as `sed 100q`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change:

```
plot for [i=1:6] "<(sed -n '1,100p' file'.i.'.dat)"  u 1:2
```

to:

```
plot for [i=1:6] "<(sed -n '1,100p' file".i.".dat)"  u 1:2
```

Note how the quotes changed. The strings go from one double quote to another. In your line there is only one string `<(sed -n '1,100p' file'.i.'.dat)` which is not what you want. In my line, there are two strings `<(sed -n '1,100p' file` and `.dat)` that are concatenated with the value of `i`.

Besides, no need to resort to `sed` to print the first 100 lines of a file, this is typically a job for `head` (`head -n 100`).